# noUiSlider not working on Heroku but works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have implemented the [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) in my rails app. But it's not working on Heroku. (placed the css and js files [here](https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider) into my app/assets/javascript and app/assets/stylesheets/ folder.**Everything works fine locally but not on heroku**

Also tried adding the two files directly using the html **link** and **script** tags but still it works only locally, though on Heroku I can see the two files being loaded.

I have the **jquery-rails** gem in my Gemfile.

my application.js:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-transition
//= require gmaps4rails.base
//= require gmaps4rails.googlemaps
//= require_tree .
```

and application.css:

```
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require _font-awesome
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

**EDIT**

Even tried with the [noUISlider rails gem](https://github.com/soycamo/jquery-nouislider-rails) but still the same problem. With this gem my application.js and application.css looks like this:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.nouislider
//= require bootstrap-transition
//= require gmaps4rails.base
//= require gmaps4rails.googlemaps
//= require_tree .  

*= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require _font-awesome
 *= require jquery.nouislider
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding (without the gem):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.nouislider" %>
```

at the bottom of the page and then in your **production.rb**

> config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.nouislider.js )

I had the same problem with another slider in rails on Heroku. Try it and comment back if you have any issues.

**UPDATE:**

I think why it's not working is because I need to call that `$(#element).noUiSlider();` after the page is loaded. So, added the `nouislider.js` to `app/assets/javascripts/` and when I call the slider function, I call it in a `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Heroku documentation on the rails asset pipeline?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Try percompiling your assets locally.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then redeploy.

Comment: But why is that necessary?

Comment: On the link there is some troubleshooting tips that describe a few reasons it might not work.  Heroku's precompile is far from perfect.  I find it better to precompile locally so I know that it is working.  I can go to the `public/assets` folder and see that everything was compiled properly.

Comment: ok but what about the direct html tag **link** and **script**. they should work out of the box.

Comment: Do you have logging enabled and have you checked `heroku logs` for errors?  Also check the javascript console on the browser for errors as well.

Comment: no errors in the browser console and neither in the heroku logs. I even tried putting the files javascript and css code to application.css and application.js but still it won't load.

Comment: Is it just the slider that isnt working or is other CSS and JS not working as well?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that slider, but it seems the error would lie with that code then.  You might want to update the question with that code and maybe someone could help you understand why their provided code does not work.

Comment: Now I even tried with another slider but the same issue. Works locally but not on Heroku. :/